# Move-Item with -Include parameter throws "item does not exist" error

Tags: powershell

I have following files:

```
> dir ~
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a----        26-Oct-18   5:30 PM        2   xxx1
-a----        26-Oct-18   5:30 PM        2   xxx2
-a----        26-Oct-18   5:30 PM        2   xxx3
-a----        26-Oct-18   5:31 PM        2   yyy1
-a----        26-Oct-18   5:31 PM        2   yyy2
-a----        26-Oct-18   5:31 PM        2   yyy3
-a----        26-Oct-18   5:33 PM        2   zzz
```

I want to move **xxx*** and **yyy*** files to another folder. So I do:

```
Move-Item -Path ~\* -Include "xxx*", "yyy*" -Destination D:\temp
```

And get an error:

```
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at '~\zzz' does not exist.
```

But the file is there and *Test-Path ~\zzz* returns *true*.

Is it a bug in *Move-Item* cmdlet or expected behavior?
If that is expected why do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... Indeed this is a bug in Windows PowerShell engine. There is an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2385) on GitHub.
It was [fixed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/3878) in PowerShell 6.0 by invoking the correct overload of `SessionState.Path.GetResolvedPSPathFromPSPath`, passing the cmdlet context object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `-Include`. Just pass the wildcards-arguments like so

```
$tmp = "D:\temp"
Move-Item "yyy*", "xxx*" -Destination "$tmp"
```

Above example assumes, that your PowerShell is in the directory where the "xxx" and "yyy" files are placed - otherwise you need to write the path in front of the wildcards

Comment: I'm interested to understand why I have a problem with "-Include" parameter.
And you do not need to write a path in front of the wildcards. Check the help:
-Include <String[]>: The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as *.txt.

Comment: If you start your PowerShell and don't switch the directory you are located at `C:\ ` - if you want to move items in the directory `C:\Users\user\Download` you indeed have to write the path in front of the wildcards

Comment: 1. When I start powershell, by default, i'm located in my home directory, which is "~".
2. If I don't have "zzz" file in my example, it works. No additional paths are required.
3. I had another question: "Is it a bug in Move-Item cmdlet or expected behavior? If that is expected why do I get it?"

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that is a bit confusing, but if you read the whole help text, what you are trying to do, the Move-Item is prefaced by Get-ChildItem in the pipeline and yes that does show the -include, but that is on the Get-ChildItem side (left side) of a pipeline.

So, again, as a best practice, what Razorfen is saying, is only ask for what you need / want. Always, do a non-destructive/impactful sanity check (i.e., that Get-ChildItem shown in the help file text) to make sure you are getting what you'd expect, before doing this sort of destructive stuff.

The fact that you are passing in the list that way, even if you did this using just the extension, the same error would occur.

```
Move-Item -Path 'D:\FileSource\*' -Include '*.txt' -Destination 'D:\FileDestination' -Verbose -WhatIf

# Results

What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\FileSource\DataSet.txt Destination: D:\FileDestination\DataSet.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\FileSource\input.txt Destination: D:\FileDestination\input.txt".
Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'D:\FileSource\processesoutput.csv' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-Item -Path 'D:\FileSource\*' -Include '*.txt' -Destination 'D:\F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Move-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

So, fully qualifying the request to work.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\FileSource\*' | Move-Item -Include '*.txt' -Destination 'D:\FileDestination' -Verbose -WhatIf

What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\FileSource\DataSet.txt Destination: D:\FileDestination\DataSet.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\FileSource\input.txt Destination: D:\FileDestination\input.txt".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: D:\FileSource\processesoutput.csv Destination: D:\FileDestination\processesoutput.csv".
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. As I said, I got the point that it should be done in other way.
But why does "Move-Item" throw 'the item at 'D:\FileSource\processesoutput.csv' does not exist' error? It exists!